# Every proper subgroup of a $p$-group (or a finite nilpotent group) is properly contained in its normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

**Question I**
Here is the picture of the proof of Theorem 1 part (4) in the 3rd edition of Dummit & Foote. The theorem is about groups of order $p^a, a \geq 1$ where $p$ is a prime, and they are denoted by $P$ throughout. The fourth part of this theorem says that if $H < P$ then $H < N_P(H),$ i.e., every proper subgroup of $P$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer in $P$. I have a question about the proof. I understand every little assertion throughout the proof, but I do not understand the big picture, namely INDUCTION. What is the base case? What is the induction hypothesis? How exactly one apply induction in group theory? Let me also tell what part (1) of the theorem says, because it is mentioned in the proof. It says that the center of $P$ is nontrivial: $Z(P) \neq 1$.

**Question II**
Now, three pages later in the text, in Theorem 3, it says that the above property also holds for finite nilpotent groups. The proof is skipped by saying that the same argument as for $p$-groups work, and the only fact we needed was if $G$ is nilpotent then so if $G/Z(G).$ I guess I don't understand this either, because I don't understand what the "argument" was for $p$-groups.

Comment: Please do not rely on images; they cannot adjust for different displays; they are not searchable (either within this site, or by search engines); most screen readers cannot process them, so that your post is unreadable for people who use them; and they are not accessible. The website has excellent typesetting capabilities through MathJax, so please use them.

Answer (score 1):

Question (1)
From the hypothesis, $P$ is a group of order $p^a$ where $a\geq 1$.
So the induction is actually on $a$.
For $a=1$, since $|P|=p$, $P$ is an abelian group. So $H$ is normal in $P$.
Therefore we have $H<P=N_P(H)$.
The induction hypothesis here is: If $L$ is a $p$-group of order $p^b$ where $b<a$, then every proper subgroup of $L$ is a proper subgroup of its normalizer in $L$.
And your last statement in Question (1) is incorrect. It should be $Z(P)\neq 1$.

Question (2)
We do induction on $|G|$.
If $|G|=1$, then $G$ does not have any proper subgroup. So the statement holds trivially.
Suppose $|G|>1$. Since $G$ is nilpotent, $Z(G)\neq 1$.
By using a similar argument, we may assume $Z(G)\leq H$ and therefore $H/Z(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $G/Z(G)$.
Since $|G/Z(G)|<|G|$ and $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent, by induction, $H/Z(G)$ is proper subgroup of $N_G(H)/Z(G)$.  Hence we get $H<N_G(H)$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, and I corrected the typo at the end of Question I. Notice that nontrivial means "is not equal to 1".